# My Racket exception handling macro does not locate source of error

Tags: exception, error-handling, macros, racket

I'm trying to implement parameterized error handling. If an error occurs and the parameter SAFE is true, then an error is raised an the program halts. But if SAFE is false, a warning is printed instead and the program continues.

```
#lang racket
(require syntax/parse/define)

;; raises parameterized error message
(define-simple-macro
  (err param:id msg)
  (if (param)
      (error msg)
      (display (format "Here be dragons: ~a\n" msg))))

;; a problematic procedure
(define (bad-thing?) (thunk #t))

;; default value of SAFE = #t
(define SAFE (make-parameter #t))

;; prints warning
(parameterize ([SAFE #f])
  (when (bad-thing?)
    (err SAFE "better watch out.")))

;; raises error
(when (bad-thing?)
  (err SAFE "Hell's bells, an exception has occurred!"))
```

The problem with the `err` macro is that when an error is raised, it traces back to where the macro is defined instead of where the problematic procedure `bad-thing?` was invoked.

There has to be a better way! Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you change `err` to be an ordinary procedure, does it work the way you want?

Comment: `(define (err param msg) (if (param) ...` gives much the same result.

Comment: So the behavior isn't specific to macros. Even if you wrapped the last `(when (bad-thing?) ...)` expression in a procedure and called it, you might not get a stack frame for the procedure because the `err` call would be in tail position and liable to be optimized away. Consider passing `error` a "who-sym" (see the docs) instead of relying on the stack trace for context.

Comment: Hmm. Nothing in the docs for "who-sym" that I could find.

Comment: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._error%29%29

Comment: Gotcha. Yes, a who-sym could be part of the solution, but it's not really what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the base `syntax-parse` instead of a higher level wrapper to get the  syntax object representing the macro call site, you can then wrap the `error` in [`syntax/loc`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fstxcase-scheme..rkt%29._syntax%2Floc%29%29) to have the location appear as it:

```lisp
#lang racket
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

;; raises parameterized error message
(define-syntax (err stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(err param:id msg)
     #`(if (param)
         #,(syntax/loc stx (error msg))
         (display (format "Here be dragons: ~a\n" msg)))]))

;; a problematic procedure
(define (bad-thing?) (thunk #t))

;; default value of SAFE = #t
(define SAFE (make-parameter #t))

;; prints warning
(parameterize ([SAFE #f])
  (when (bad-thing?)
    (err SAFE "better watch out.")))

;; raises error
(when (bad-thing?)
  (err SAFE "Hell's bells, an exception has occurred!"))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!